Why does CustomStringConvertible not work for Data?
I have the following:
extension Data : CustomStringConvertible {
    var description : String {
        return base64EncodedString()
    }
}

This shows a warning:
Conformance of 'Data' to protocol 'CustomStringConvertible' was already stated in the type's module 'Foundation'
And because of this warning, Data isn't printed using the description.
Is this not supported?

As Claus Jørgensen's answer says, you cannot "override" the protocol witness description in your own extension.
If the whole purpose of doing this is just so you can directly print the data, there is an alternative.
You see, print doesn't just use CustomStringConvertible.description to print values. print just uses String.init(describing:) to work out what string to print, and String.init(describing:) would first check if the value conforms to TextOutputStreamable, before it checks for CustomStringConvertible conformance.
Luckily, Data doesn't conform to TextOutputStreamable, so you can write
extension Data : @retroactive TextOutputStreamable {
    public func write<Target>(to target: inout Target) where Target : TextOutputStream {
        target.write(base64EncodedString())
    }
}

That said, this would be a problem when in some future version Data does conform to TextOutputStreamable. Therefore, the best thing to do is to bite the bullet and explicitly write data.base64EncodedString() in your print calls.

As the error says, Data already conforms to CustomStringConvertible (and CustomDebugStringConvertible) and thus already have a description property.
You cannot override this property (nor can you inherit from Data, as it's a struct)
Instead you need to (and should) create a different property for your custom description.
For example:
extension Data {
    var base64Description: String {
        return base64EncodedString()
    }
}

However it's somewhat pointless, as you might as well just call the method directly, unless there's more to your code.

The reason I was trying to override description was because print() uses it. I guess it's not possible then.

@sudoExclamationExclamation If it's really really important to you, then wrap Data in something (since you cannot inherit from it).
